# porting navigation package to android

Tags: navigation, turtlebot, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to setup a master using a Thinkpad Notebook, and driving a robot base(such as turtlebot) using a android device. I have tested the demo application, http://wiki.ros.org/android_ndk/Tutorials/move_baseNativeActivityApplication, it works well. So I guess that it would be possible to porting the navigation stack on the android.

On android device, it will control the robot base, so I will write code to control the base and publish base status, robot pose, etc.

Besides the robot base control, **My question is how to implement the navigation on the android device? My goal is: user touch a point on the android device screen(map on the screen), then the android device will drive the robot base to the touch point.**

I guess I should do the following works:

1. I will need to write node on android to get map from the master.
2. write node on android to read the kinect data and publish as the laser data or point cloud for navigation.

what else should I do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249618/porting-navigation-package-to-android/) by [xhsoldier](https://answers.ros.org/users/28621/xhsoldier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-12-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [peterwe](https://answers.ros.org/users/28779/peterwe/) on 2018-01-12**:
Hello @xhsoldier,

did you already manage to get the navigation package up and running on android? How did you do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@xhsoldier take a look at https://github.com/ekumenlabs/tangobot and https://wiki.ros.org/Robots/Tangobot.

That already has the functionality that you need, and it's open source: the robot can move to a goal given by a second Android device. The only detail is that you will need a Tango enabled phone for the robot.

You can also take a look at the code to see how the navigation stack was ported and how to execute it on Android.

---

Originally posted by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) with karma: 1054 on 2017-10-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0